# How do I put the remarks and footers of a long table made with the tabularray package on all pages?

Tags: tables, footnotes, tabularray

I am making a long table using `longtblr` from the `tabularray` package. This table has some notes and footers, which appear on the last page where the table is.

I want to know if there is any way to put at the bottom of the table, on every page it is on, all the remarks (`remark={text}`) and the footers (`note={text}`), keeping the text "**Continued on next page**".

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
caption={Caption},
label={tab:label},
remark{Note}={I want this note on every page where the longtblr is}
]{%
hlines,
vlines,
rowhead=1,
colspec={X[l,m]}
}

\textbf{Header}\\
\blindtext \\
\blindtext \\
\blindtext \\
\blindtext \\
\blindtext \\
\blindtext \\
\blindtext \\
\blindtext \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

## First and second page:

[image]

## Last page

[image]

Comment: If you have multiline `notes` or `remarks`, have a look at the new solution I posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may define a new theme with the note in the continuation text in the foot by defining a new template for the continuation text.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%-----------------------added----------------------------
\NewTblrTheme{MyTheme}{
    \DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{MyTmp}{%
            \raggedright\UseTblrTemplate{remark}{default}
            Continued on next page
    }
    \SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{MyTmp}
}
%---------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
        theme = MyTheme, %<--- added
        caption={Caption},
        label={tab:label},
        remark{Note}={I want this note on every page where the longtblr is}
        ]{%
        hlines,
        vlines,
        rowhead=1,
        colspec={X[l,m]},
    }
        \textbf{Header}\\
        \blindtext \\
        \blindtext \\
        \blindtext \\
        \blindtext \\
        \blindtext \\
        \blindtext \\
        \blindtext \\
        \blindtext \\
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would like to present an improved solution off Imran's solution. In my opinion, it is better to place the `note` (and `remark`) templates inside `firstfoot` and `middlefoot` and not in the `contfoot-text` template. This ensures the correct justification for multiline `notes` and `remarks`. Also, for consistency, one should use `contfoot` template and not hardcode the text.

I choose to specify this as default, but of course you can also use this in a `theme` as in Imran's solution.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Notes and remarks on every page
\DefTblrTemplate{firstfoot, middlefoot}{default}{%
    \UseTblrTemplate{note}{default}
    \UseTblrTemplate{remark}{default}
    \UseTblrTemplate{contfoot}{default}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption={Caption},
        label={tab:label},
        remark{Note}={I want this note on every page where the longtblr is},
        remark{Long Source}={This is a really long source, which will break over several lines. Using the correct templates ensures that the justification remains. With raggedright, the right side of multine notes and remarks will not be justified, which looks odd.}
        ]{%
            hlines,
            vlines,
            rowhead=1,
            colspec={X[l,m]},
        }
        \textbf{Header}\\
        \blindtext \\
        \blindtext \\
        \blindtext \\
        \blindtext \\
        \blindtext \\
        \blindtext \\
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image: first page]

[image: second page]

[image: third page]