# tabularx pagebreak from a specific line

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have a long table (consisting of 3 separate tables) and I would like to cut it into 2. At bottom of the page, I would like to see 2 tables and the top of the following page the last table. Many thanks in advance.

```
  \documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,filecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newcommand{\etal}{{\sl et al. }}
\newcommand{\argmax}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmax}}
\newcommand{\iid}{\stackrel{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{appendix}

%\usepackage{ltablex}

%\pdfminorversion=4
% NOTE: To produce blinded version, replace "0" with "1" below.
\newcommand{\blind}{1}

% DON'T change margins - should be 1 inch all around.
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5in}%
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.5in}%
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}%
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.3in}%
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.8in}%




\begin{document}
    
    %\bibliographystyle{natbib}
    
    \def\spacingset#1{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}%
        {#1}\small\normalsize} \spacingset{1}
        

    \newpage
    \spacingset{1.45} % DON'T change the spacing!


\begin{table}[!ht] %[!ht]
    \footnotesize
    %%\scriptsize
    \centering 
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{l*{9}{R}}
        
        \toprule    
        Variables  &  Fml  &  Infm  &  Both  &  Fml  &  Infm  &  Both  &  Fml  &  Infm  &  Both \\ \midrule 
        %\addlinespace
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{BchMk} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{CCP.0} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{CCP.1} \\ 
        \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10}   
        %\addlinespace
        Gender  & 0.84$^{***}$ & 1.11$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ & 0.87$^{***}$ &   1.17$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ & 0.84$^{***}$ &  1.15$^{***}$ &   0.97$^{***}$ \\
        Marital Status& 1.94$^{***}$ &   1.15$^{***}$ &  1.93$^{***}$ &  1.45$^{***}$ &  1.16$^{***}$ &  2.53$^{***}$  &1.94$^{***}$ &   1.13$^{***}$ &  1.95$^{***}$\\
        Age &    0.95$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$ &  0.94$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ &  0.94$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$\\
        Employed    & 1.61$^{***}$ &     1.07$^{***}$ &  1.57$^{***}$ &  1.72$^{***}$ &  1.20$^{***}$ &  2.30$^{***}$ &  1.57$^{***}$ &  1.01$^{***}$ &  1.38$^{***}$  \\
        Education &  2.08$^{***}$ &  0.62$^{***}$ &  1.16$^{***}$ &  1.97$^{***}$ &  0.73$^{***}$ &  1.28$^{***}$  & 2.04$^{***}$ &  0.65$^{***}$ &  1.07$^{***}$\\
        Party&   1.44$^{***}$ &  0.78$^{***}$ &  1.13$^{***}$ &  -----  & -----   & -----  &    -----   & -----  & -----    \\
        HR  & 1.52$^{***}$ &     0.65$^{***}$ &  0.72$^{***}$ & 1.77$^{***}$ &   0.51$^{***}$ &  0.58$^{***}$  &     1.50$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.80$^{***}$  \\
        Region-East &    0.77$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.56$^{***}$ & 0.95$^{***}$ &   0.54$^{***}$ &  0.58$^{***}$   &    0.78$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.51$^{***}$\\
        Region-Center &  0.64$^{***}$ &  1.03$^{***}$ &  0.76$^{***}$ &  0.90$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ &  0.84$^{***}$  &     0.60$^{***}$ &  1.01$^{***}$ &  0.72$^{***}$\\
        Fin.Inter &  1.23$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  1.10$^{***}$ & 1.10$^{***}$ &   0.77$^{***}$ &  1.17$^{***}$ & 1.23$^{***}$ &   1.02$^{***}$ &  1.07$^{***}$   \\
        Fin.Knowledge   & 2.08$^{***}$ &     0.80$^{***}$ &  2.11$^{***}$ &  1.58$^{***}$ &  0.57$^{***}$ &  2.00$^{***}$ &  2.18$^{***}$ &  0.94$^{***}$ &  2.38$^{***}$   \\
        Income  & 1.00$^{***}$ &     1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{*}$ &    1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$   \\
        Networth &   1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{**}$ &   1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$\\
        \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10} 
        Observations   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{26212} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{21183}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{5028}\\ 
        AIC  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{42,266.04} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{7,688.11}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{34,686.78}\\ 
        \toprule 
        %\addlinespace
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{BchMk} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{CCP.0} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{CCP.1} \\ 
        \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10} 
        %\addlinespace 
        Gender  &    0.83$^{***}$ &  1.11$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ &  0.86$^{***}$ &  1.17$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$  & 0.84$^{***}$ & 1.15$^{***}$ & 0.98$^{***}$   \\
        Marital Status  &    1.98$^{***}$ &  1.14$^{***}$ &  1.97$^{***}$ & 1.48$^{***}$ &   1.15$^{***}$ &  2.57$^{***}$  & 1.98$^{***}$ &  1.13$^{***}$ &  1.97$^{***}$    \\
        Age  &   0.95$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$ &  0.94$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ &  0.94$^{***}$  &     0.95$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$   \\
        Employed  &  1.60$^{***}$ &  1.06$^{***}$ &  1.56$^{***}$ &  1.69$^{***}$ &  1.20$^{***}$ &  2.27$^{***}$ &  1.57$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.36$^{***}$  \\
        Education  & 2.12$^{***}$ &  0.62$^{***}$ &  1.19$^{***}$ &  2.02$^{***}$ &  0.73$^{***}$ &  1.31$^{***}$  &     2.11$^{***}$ &  0.64$^{***}$ &  1.10$^{***}$    \\
        Party  &     1.45$^{***}$ &  0.78$^{***}$ &  1.14$^{***}$ &     -----  &    -----   & ----- & -----     & -----     & ----- \\
        HR  &    1.56$^{***}$ &  0.64$^{***}$ &  0.74$^{***}$ &  1.83$^{***}$ &  0.50$^{***}$ &  0.60$^{***}$  &     1.54$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.81$^{***}$ \\
        Region-East  &   0.79$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.58$^{***}$ & 1.00$^{***}$ &   0.54$^{***}$ &  0.61$^{***}$ &  0.79$^{***}$ &  0.65$^{***}$ &  0.55$^{***}$  \\
        Region-Center  &     0.64$^{***}$ &  1.03$^{***}$ &  0.76$^{***}$ &  0.90$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ &  0.85$^{***}$  &     0.59$^{***}$ &  1.01$^{***}$ &  0.74$^{***}$   \\
        Fin.Inter  &     1.24$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  1.12$^{***}$ &  1.11$^{***}$ &  0.77$^{***}$ &  1.18$^{***}$  &     1.25$^{***}$ &  1.02$^{***}$ &  1.09$^{***}$     \\
        Fin.Knowledge  &     2.14$^{***}$ &  0.79$^{***}$ &  2.19$^{***}$ & 1.60$^{***}$ &   0.57$^{***}$ &  2.05$^{***}$   &    2.21$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  2.39$^{***}$  \\
        Income  &    1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{**}$ &   1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$  \\
        NW-HE &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ & 1.00$^{***}$ &   1.00$^{*}$ &    1.00$^{**}$  &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$\\
        \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10}       
        Observations  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{26212} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{21183} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{5028}\\
        AIC  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{42,422.85} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{7,732.85}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{34,802.33}\\ 
        \toprule 
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{BchMk} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{CCP.0} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{CCP.1} \\ 
        \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10} 
        %\addlinespace 
        Gender  &    0.84$^{***}$ &  1.11$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ &  0.87$^{***}$ &  1.17$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.85$^{***}$ &  1.15$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$     \\
        Marital Status  &    1.93$^{***}$ &  1.15$^{***}$ &  1.92$^{***}$ &  1.44$^{***}$ &  1.15$^{***}$ &  2.50$^{***}$ &  1.93$^{***}$ &  1.13$^{***}$ &  1.93$^{***}$  \\
        Age  &   0.95$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$ & 0.94$^{***}$ &   0.97$^{***}$ &  0.94$^{***}$  &     0.95$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$ \\
        Employed  &  1.61$^{***}$ &  1.07$^{***}$ &  1.57$^{***}$ & 1.72$^{***}$ &   1.19$^{***}$ &  2.31$^{***}$ &  1.58$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.37$^{***}$  \\
        Education  &     2.07$^{***}$ &  0.62$^{***}$ &  1.16$^{***}$ & 1.96$^{***}$ &   0.73$^{***}$ &  1.28$^{***}$  &     2.07$^{***}$ &  0.65$^{***}$ &  1.07$^{***}$  \\
        Party  &     1.43$^{***}$ &  0.78$^{***}$ &  1.13$^{***}$ &     -----  & -----    &   ----- & -----       & -----   &   -----  \\
        HR  &    1.51$^{***}$ &  0.64$^{***}$ &  0.72$^{***}$ &  1.76$^{***}$ &  0.51$^{***}$ &  0.58$^{***}$  &     1.49$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.78$^{***}$ \\
        Region-East  &   0.77$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.56$^{***}$ & 0.94$^{***}$ &   0.54$^{***}$ &  0.57$^{***}$  &     0.77$^{***}$ &  0.65$^{***}$ &  0.53$^{***}$    \\
        Region-Center  &     0.64$^{***}$ &  1.03$^{***}$ &  0.76$^{***}$ &  0.90$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ &  0.84$^{***}$ &  0.60$^{***}$ &  1.01$^{***}$ &  0.75$^{***}$   \\
        Fin.Inter  &     1.22$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  1.10$^{***}$ & 1.10$^{***}$ &   0.77$^{***}$ &  1.17$^{***}$   &    1.23$^{***}$ &  1.02$^{***}$ &  1.08$^{***}$ \\
        Fin.Knowldge  &  2.07$^{***}$ &  0.79$^{***}$ &  2.10$^{***}$ & 1.57$^{***}$ &   0.57$^{***}$ &  1.99$^{***}$ &  2.14$^{***}$ &  0.99$^{***}$ &  2.30$^{***}$  \\
        Income  &    1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ & 1.00$^{***}$ &   1.00$^{*}$ &    1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$\\
        Liquid Assets  &     1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ & 1.00$^{***}$ &   1.00$^{**}$ &   1.00$^{***}$  &     1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$  \\
        \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10}   
        Observations  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{26212} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{21183} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{5028}\\
        AIC   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{42,258.51} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{7,681.80}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{34,677.61}\\ 
        %   Log Likelihood  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{BLA} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{BLA}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{BLA}\\ 
        \bottomrule
        \addlinespace
        \multicolumn{10}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\footnotesize Note: Multinominal Logistic Model with Networth as Predictor. Relative Risk Ratios (RRR) are reported with significance: $^*p<0.1;~^{**}p<0.05;~^{***}p<0.01$. 
            The variables and abbreviations can be found 
            %in Appendix \ref{tab:def.of.vars} and Appendix \ref{tab:abbreviations}, respectively. 
        }\\
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{MLM.1: Multinominal logistic models }
    %\label{tab:MLM-1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You cannot break a `tabularx` across pages.

Comment: Consider using a `longtable` or `longtblr` (from `tabularray` package). Their allow tables to flow over several pages and you can customize where the pagebreaks should happen. `longtblr` also supports `X` column type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `longtblr` environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,filecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newcommand{\etal}{{\sl et al. }}
\newcommand{\argmax}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmax}}
\newcommand{\iid}{\stackrel{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{appendix}

%\usepackage{ltablex}

%\pdfminorversion=4
% NOTE: To produce blinded version, replace "0" with "1" below.
\newcommand{\blind}{1}

% DON'T change margins - should be 1 inch all around.
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5in}%
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.5in}%
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}%
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.3in}%
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.8in}%

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
    %\bibliographystyle{natbib}
    
    \def\spacingset#1{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}%
        {#1}\small\normalsize} \spacingset{1}
    
    
    \newpage
    \spacingset{1.4} % DON'T change the spacing!
    
    \footnotesize
    \begin{longtblr}[
            caption={MLM.1: Multinominal logistic models},
            label={tab:MLM-1},
            remark{Note} = {Multinominal Logistic Model with Networth as Predictor. Relative Risk Ratios (RRR) are reported with significance: $^*p<0.1;~^{**}p<0.05;~^{***}p<0.01$.},
            remark{Source} = {The variables and abbreviations can be found in Appendix \ref{tab:def.of.vars} and Appendix \ref{tab:abbreviations}, respectively.},
        ]{
            colspec=l*{9}X,
            rowhead=1,
        }       
        \toprule    
        Variables  &  Fml  &  Infm  &  Both  &  Fml  &  Infm  &  Both  &  Fml  &  Infm  &  Both \\ \midrule 
        & \SetCell[c=3]{c} BchMk &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} CCP.0 &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} CCP.1 &&\\
        \cmidrule[lr]{2-4}\cmidrule[lr]{5-7}\cmidrule[lr]{8-10}
        Gender  & 0.84$^{***}$ & 1.11$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ & 0.87$^{***}$ &   1.17$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ & 0.84$^{***}$ &  1.15$^{***}$ &   0.97$^{***}$ \\
        Marital Status& 1.94$^{***}$ &   1.15$^{***}$ &  1.93$^{***}$ &  1.45$^{***}$ &  1.16$^{***}$ &  2.53$^{***}$  &1.94$^{***}$ &   1.13$^{***}$ &  1.95$^{***}$\\
        Age &    0.95$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$ &  0.94$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ &  0.94$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$\\
        Employed    & 1.61$^{***}$ &     1.07$^{***}$ &  1.57$^{***}$ &  1.72$^{***}$ &  1.20$^{***}$ &  2.30$^{***}$ &  1.57$^{***}$ &  1.01$^{***}$ &  1.38$^{***}$  \\
        Education &  2.08$^{***}$ &  0.62$^{***}$ &  1.16$^{***}$ &  1.97$^{***}$ &  0.73$^{***}$ &  1.28$^{***}$  & 2.04$^{***}$ &  0.65$^{***}$ &  1.07$^{***}$\\
        Party&   1.44$^{***}$ &  0.78$^{***}$ &  1.13$^{***}$ &  -----  & -----   & -----  &    -----   & -----  & -----    \\
        HR  & 1.52$^{***}$ &     0.65$^{***}$ &  0.72$^{***}$ & 1.77$^{***}$ &   0.51$^{***}$ &  0.58$^{***}$  &     1.50$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.80$^{***}$  \\
        Region-East &    0.77$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.56$^{***}$ & 0.95$^{***}$ &   0.54$^{***}$ &  0.58$^{***}$   &    0.78$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.51$^{***}$\\
        Region-Center &  0.64$^{***}$ &  1.03$^{***}$ &  0.76$^{***}$ &  0.90$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ &  0.84$^{***}$  &     0.60$^{***}$ &  1.01$^{***}$ &  0.72$^{***}$\\
        Fin.Inter &  1.23$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  1.10$^{***}$ & 1.10$^{***}$ &   0.77$^{***}$ &  1.17$^{***}$ & 1.23$^{***}$ &   1.02$^{***}$ &  1.07$^{***}$   \\
        Fin.Knowledge   & 2.08$^{***}$ &     0.80$^{***}$ &  2.11$^{***}$ &  1.58$^{***}$ &  0.57$^{***}$ &  2.00$^{***}$ &  2.18$^{***}$ &  0.94$^{***}$ &  2.38$^{***}$   \\
        Income  & 1.00$^{***}$ &     1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{*}$ &    1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$   \\
        Networth &   1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{**}$ &   1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$\\
        \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule[lr]{2-4}\cmidrule[lr]{5-7}\cmidrule[lr]{8-10} 
        Observations   & \SetCell[c=3]{c} 26212 &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} 21183 &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c}5028 &&\\
        AIC  & \SetCell[c=3]{c} 42,266.04 &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} 7,688.11 &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} 34,686.78 &&\\
        \toprule
        & \SetCell[c=3]{c} BchMk &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} CCP.0 &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} CCP.1 &&\\
        \cmidrule[lr]{2-4}\cmidrule[lr]{5-7}\cmidrule[lr]{8-10}
        Gender  &    0.83$^{***}$ &  1.11$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ &  0.86$^{***}$ &  1.17$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$  & 0.84$^{***}$ & 1.15$^{***}$ & 0.98$^{***}$   \\
        Marital Status  &    1.98$^{***}$ &  1.14$^{***}$ &  1.97$^{***}$ & 1.48$^{***}$ &   1.15$^{***}$ &  2.57$^{***}$  & 1.98$^{***}$ &  1.13$^{***}$ &  1.97$^{***}$    \\
        Age  &   0.95$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$ &  0.94$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ &  0.94$^{***}$  &     0.95$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$   \\
        Employed  &  1.60$^{***}$ &  1.06$^{***}$ &  1.56$^{***}$ &  1.69$^{***}$ &  1.20$^{***}$ &  2.27$^{***}$ &  1.57$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.36$^{***}$  \\
        Education  & 2.12$^{***}$ &  0.62$^{***}$ &  1.19$^{***}$ &  2.02$^{***}$ &  0.73$^{***}$ &  1.31$^{***}$  &     2.11$^{***}$ &  0.64$^{***}$ &  1.10$^{***}$    \\
        Party  &     1.45$^{***}$ &  0.78$^{***}$ &  1.14$^{***}$ &     -----  &    -----   & ----- & -----     & -----     & ----- \\
        HR  &    1.56$^{***}$ &  0.64$^{***}$ &  0.74$^{***}$ &  1.83$^{***}$ &  0.50$^{***}$ &  0.60$^{***}$  &     1.54$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.81$^{***}$ \\
        Region-East  &   0.79$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.58$^{***}$ & 1.00$^{***}$ &   0.54$^{***}$ &  0.61$^{***}$ &  0.79$^{***}$ &  0.65$^{***}$ &  0.55$^{***}$  \\
        Region-Center  &     0.64$^{***}$ &  1.03$^{***}$ &  0.76$^{***}$ &  0.90$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ &  0.85$^{***}$  &     0.59$^{***}$ &  1.01$^{***}$ &  0.74$^{***}$   \\
        Fin.Inter  &     1.24$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  1.12$^{***}$ &  1.11$^{***}$ &  0.77$^{***}$ &  1.18$^{***}$  &     1.25$^{***}$ &  1.02$^{***}$ &  1.09$^{***}$     \\
        Fin.Knowledge  &     2.14$^{***}$ &  0.79$^{***}$ &  2.19$^{***}$ & 1.60$^{***}$ &   0.57$^{***}$ &  2.05$^{***}$   &    2.21$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  2.39$^{***}$  \\
        Income  &    1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{**}$ &   1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$  \\
        NW-HE &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ & 1.00$^{***}$ &   1.00$^{*}$ &    1.00$^{**}$  &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$\\
                \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule[lr]{2-4}\cmidrule[lr]{5-7}\cmidrule[lr]{8-10} 
        Observations   & \SetCell[c=3]{c} 26212 &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} 21183 &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c}5028 &&\\
        AIC  & \SetCell[c=3]{c} 42,266.04 &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} 7,688.11 &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} 34,686.78 &&\\
        \toprule
        & \SetCell[c=3]{c} BchMk &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} CCP.0 &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} CCP.1 &&\\
        \cmidrule[lr]{2-4}\cmidrule[lr]{5-7}\cmidrule[lr]{8-10}
        Gender  &    0.84$^{***}$ &  1.11$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ &  0.87$^{***}$ &  1.17$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.85$^{***}$ &  1.15$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$     \\
        Marital Status  &    1.93$^{***}$ &  1.15$^{***}$ &  1.92$^{***}$ &  1.44$^{***}$ &  1.15$^{***}$ &  2.50$^{***}$ &  1.93$^{***}$ &  1.13$^{***}$ &  1.93$^{***}$  \\
        Age  &   0.95$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$ & 0.94$^{***}$ &   0.97$^{***}$ &  0.94$^{***}$  &     0.95$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$ \\
        Employed  &  1.61$^{***}$ &  1.07$^{***}$ &  1.57$^{***}$ & 1.72$^{***}$ &   1.19$^{***}$ &  2.31$^{***}$ &  1.58$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.37$^{***}$  \\
        Education  &     2.07$^{***}$ &  0.62$^{***}$ &  1.16$^{***}$ & 1.96$^{***}$ &   0.73$^{***}$ &  1.28$^{***}$  &     2.07$^{***}$ &  0.65$^{***}$ &  1.07$^{***}$  \\
        Party  &     1.43$^{***}$ &  0.78$^{***}$ &  1.13$^{***}$ &     -----  & -----    &   ----- & -----       & -----   &   -----  \\
        HR  &    1.51$^{***}$ &  0.64$^{***}$ &  0.72$^{***}$ &  1.76$^{***}$ &  0.51$^{***}$ &  0.58$^{***}$  &     1.49$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.78$^{***}$ \\
        Region-East  &   0.77$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.56$^{***}$ & 0.94$^{***}$ &   0.54$^{***}$ &  0.57$^{***}$  &     0.77$^{***}$ &  0.65$^{***}$ &  0.53$^{***}$    \\
        Region-Center  &     0.64$^{***}$ &  1.03$^{***}$ &  0.76$^{***}$ &  0.90$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ &  0.84$^{***}$ &  0.60$^{***}$ &  1.01$^{***}$ &  0.75$^{***}$   \\
        Fin.Inter  &     1.22$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  1.10$^{***}$ & 1.10$^{***}$ &   0.77$^{***}$ &  1.17$^{***}$   &    1.23$^{***}$ &  1.02$^{***}$ &  1.08$^{***}$ \\
        Fin.Knowldge  &  2.07$^{***}$ &  0.79$^{***}$ &  2.10$^{***}$ & 1.57$^{***}$ &   0.57$^{***}$ &  1.99$^{***}$ &  2.14$^{***}$ &  0.99$^{***}$ &  2.30$^{***}$  \\
        Income  &    1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ & 1.00$^{***}$ &   1.00$^{*}$ &    1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$\\
        Liquid Assets  &     1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ & 1.00$^{***}$ &   1.00$^{**}$ &   1.00$^{***}$  &     1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$  \\
        \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule[lr]{2-4}\cmidrule[lr]{5-7}\cmidrule[lr]{8-10} 
        Observations   & \SetCell[c=3]{c} 26212 &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} 21183 &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c}5028 &&\\*
        AIC  & \SetCell[c=3]{c} 42,266.04 &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} 7,688.11 &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} 34,686.78 &&\\*
        \toprule
        Log Likelihood & \SetCell[c=3]{c} BLA &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} BLA &&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} BLA &&\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
    
\end{document}
```

This will automatically flow over multiple pages.

[image: longtblr solution]

If you don't want a pagebreak for a specify row you can use `\\*`. You can also force a pagebreak with `\pagebreak`. However, in this case I changed the `\spacingset` so that the pagebreak occurs at the right place. I have also added your note and source as `remarks`.

`rowhead=1` causes the first head of the table to repeat, so your readers know the meaning of the columns of the second page.

Comment: thank you very much but I can not run this code properly.

Comment: What error to you get? Please consider updating your tex-distribution, as the `tabularray` package is fairly new.

Comment: @SeymaKalay I misunderstood your question. I changed the answers and I think the output is now what you want

Answer (score 2):

For exercise:

- use of `longtblr` table (defined in the `tabularray` package)
- grouping rows, after each third row is inserted vertical space (of 5pt)
- remarks are on bottom of each table part
- font size in table is `\small`
- for marking of values is used `\TblrNote` (in spirit of `tabularray` syntax)
- table is broken manually after second sub-table

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{afterpage}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage[skip=0.5ex,
            font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\NewTblrTheme{remark on each foot}{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628632
    \DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{Remark}{%
            \raggedright\UseTblrTemplate{remark}{default}\medskip\itshape
            Continued on next page
    }
\SetTblrStyle{contfoot-text}{font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}
\SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{Remark}
}

  \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachthree}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {3}{3}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    
    \begin{longtblr}[
  theme = remark on each foot,
caption = {MLM.1: Multinominal logistic models},
  label = {tab:MLM-1},
  remark{Note} = {Multinominal Logistic Model with Networth as Predictor.
                  Relative Risk Ratios (RRR) are reported with significance: $^*p<0.1;~^{**}p<0.05;~^{***}p<0.01$.},
remark{Source} = {The variables and abbreviations can be found in
                  Appendix \ref{tab:def.of.vars} and Appendix \ref{tab:abbreviations}, respectively.},
                    ]{
        rowhead = 2,
        rows = {font=\small},
        colsep = 3pt,
        colspec= {@{} l *{9}{X[c, si={table-format=1.2{***}}]} @{}},
        rowsep = 0.2pt,
        row{eachthree} = {abovesep=5pt},
                     }
    \toprule
\SetRow{font=\small\bfseries}
        & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {{{BchMk}}} &  &
                &\SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{CCP.0}}}  &  &
                       &\SetCell[c=3]{c}  {{{CCP.1}}}  &  & \\
Variables
        & {{{Fml}}}     & {{{Infm}}}    & {{{Both}}}
        & {{{Fml}}}     & {{{Infm}}}    & {{{Both}}}
        & {{{Fml}}}     & {{{Infm}}}    & {{{Both}}}    \\
        \cmidrule[lr]{2-4}
                \cmidrule[lr]{5-7}
                        \cmidrule[l]{8-10}
Gender  & 0.84\TblrNote{***} & 1.11\TblrNote{***} & 0.97\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.87\TblrNote{***} & 1.17\TblrNote{***} & 0.98\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.84\TblrNote{***} & 1.15\TblrNote{***} & 0.97\TblrNote{***}  \\
Marital Status
        & 1.94\TblrNote{***} & 1.15\TblrNote{***} & 1.93\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.45\TblrNote{***} & 1.16\TblrNote{***} & 2.53\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.94\TblrNote{***} & 1.13\TblrNote{***} & 1.95\TblrNote{***}  \\
Age     & 0.95\TblrNote{***} & 0.98\TblrNote{***} & 0.95\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.94\TblrNote{***} & 0.97\TblrNote{***} & 0.94\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.95\TblrNote{***} & 0.98\TblrNote{***} & 0.95\TblrNote{***}  \\
Employed
        & 1.61\TblrNote{***} & 1.07\TblrNote{***} & 1.57\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.72\TblrNote{***} & 1.20\TblrNote{***} & 2.30\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.57\TblrNote{***} & 1.01\TblrNote{***} & 1.38\TblrNote{***}  \\
Education
        & 2.08\TblrNote{***} & 0.62\TblrNote{***} & 1.16\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.97\TblrNote{***} & 0.73\TblrNote{***} & 1.28\TblrNote{***}
        & 2.04\TblrNote{***} & 0.65\TblrNote{***} & 1.07\TblrNote{***}  \\
Party   & 1.44\TblrNote{***} & 0.78\TblrNote{***} & 1.13\TblrNote{***}
            & {{{---}}} & {{{---}}} &{{{---}}}
                            & {{{---}}} & {{{--}}} & {{{---}}}          \\
HR      & 1.52\TblrNote{***} & 0.65\TblrNote{***} & 0.72\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.77\TblrNote{***} & 0.51\TblrNote{***} & 0.58\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.50\TblrNote{***} & 0.66\TblrNote{***} & 0.80\TblrNote{***}  \\
Region-East
        & 0.77\TblrNote{***} & 0.66\TblrNote{***} & 0.56\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.95\TblrNote{***} & 0.54\TblrNote{***} & 0.58\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.78\TblrNote{***} & 0.66\TblrNote{***} & 0.51\TblrNote{***}  \\
Region-Center
        & 0.64\TblrNote{***} & 1.03\TblrNote{***} & 0.76\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.90\TblrNote{***} & 0.97\TblrNote{***} & 0.84\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.60\TblrNote{***} & 1.01\TblrNote{***} & 0.72\TblrNote{***}  \\
Fin. Inter
        & 1.23\TblrNote{***} & 0.98\TblrNote{***} & 1.10\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.10\TblrNote{***} & 0.77\TblrNote{***} & 1.17\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.23\TblrNote{***} & 1.02\TblrNote{***} & 1.07\TblrNote{***}  \\
Fin. Knowledge
        & 2.08\TblrNote{***} & 0.80\TblrNote{***} & 2.11\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.58\TblrNote{***} & 0.57\TblrNote{***} & 2.00\TblrNote{***}
        & 2.18\TblrNote{***} & 0.94\TblrNote{***} & 2.38\TblrNote{***}  \\
Income  & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{*}   & 1.00\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***}  \\
Networth
        & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{**}  &  1.00\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***}  \\
        \cmidrule[lr]{2-4}
                \cmidrule[lr]{5-7}
                        \cmidrule[l]{8-10}
Observations
    & \SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{26212}}}  &   &
            & \SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{21183}}} &  &
                    & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {{{5028}}}  &  &                \\
AIC & \SetCell[c=3]{c}    {{{42,258.51}}}   &  &
            & \SetCell[c=3]{c}    {{{7,681.80}}}  &  &
                    & \SetCell[c=3]{c}    {{{34,677.61}}} &   &         \\
Log Likelihood
\SetRow{font=\small\bfseries}
    &  \SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{BLA}}} &   &
            & \SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{BLA}}}  &   &
                & \SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{BLA}}}  &   &                     \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\SetRow{font=\small\bfseries}
        & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {{{BchMk}}} &  &
                &\SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{CCP.0}}}  &  &
                       &\SetCell[c=3]{c}  {{{CCP.1}}}  &  &             \\
Variables
        & {{{Fml}}}     & {{{Infm}}}    & {{{Both}}}
        & {{{Fml}}}     & {{{Infm}}}    & {{{Both}}}
        & {{{Fml}}}     & {{{Infm}}}    & {{{Both}}}                    \\
        \cmidrule[lr]{2-4}
                \cmidrule[lr=-0.5]{5-7}
                        \cmidrule[l=-0.5]{8-10}
Gender  & 0.84\TblrNote{***} & 1.11\TblrNote{***} & 0.97\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.87\TblrNote{***} & 1.17\TblrNote{***} & 0.98\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.84\TblrNote{***} & 1.15\TblrNote{***} & 0.97\TblrNote{***}  \\
Marital Status
        & 1.94\TblrNote{***} & 1.15\TblrNote{***} & 1.93\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.45\TblrNote{***} & 1.16\TblrNote{***} & 2.53\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.94\TblrNote{***} & 1.13\TblrNote{***} & 1.95\TblrNote{***}  \\
Age     & 0.95\TblrNote{***} & 0.98\TblrNote{***} & 0.95\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.94\TblrNote{***} & 0.97\TblrNote{***} & 0.94\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.95\TblrNote{***} & 0.98\TblrNote{***} & 0.95\TblrNote{***}  \\
Employed
        & 1.61\TblrNote{***} & 1.07\TblrNote{***} & 1.57\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.72\TblrNote{***} & 1.20\TblrNote{***} & 2.30\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.57\TblrNote{***} & 1.01\TblrNote{***} & 1.38\TblrNote{***}  \\
Education
        & 2.08\TblrNote{***} & 0.62\TblrNote{***} & 1.16\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.97\TblrNote{***} & 0.73\TblrNote{***} & 1.28\TblrNote{***}
        & 2.04\TblrNote{***} & 0.65\TblrNote{***} & 1.07\TblrNote{***}  \\
Party   & 1.44\TblrNote{***} & 0.78\TblrNote{***} & 1.13\TblrNote{***}
            & {{{---}}} & {{{---}}} &{{{---}}}
                             & {{{---}}} & {{{---}}} & {{{---}}}        \\
HR      & 1.52\TblrNote{***} & 0.65\TblrNote{***} & 0.72\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.77\TblrNote{***} & 0.51\TblrNote{***} & 0.58\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.50\TblrNote{***} & 0.66\TblrNote{***} & 0.80\TblrNote{***}  \\
Region-East
        & 0.77\TblrNote{***} & 0.66\TblrNote{***} & 0.56\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.95\TblrNote{***} & 0.54\TblrNote{***} & 0.58\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.78\TblrNote{***} & 0.66\TblrNote{***} & 0.51\TblrNote{***}  \\
Region-Center
        & 0.64\TblrNote{***} & 1.03\TblrNote{***} & 0.76\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.90\TblrNote{***} & 0.97\TblrNote{***} & 0.84\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.60\TblrNote{***} & 1.01\TblrNote{***} & 0.72\TblrNote{***}  \\
Fin. Inter
        & 1.23\TblrNote{***} & 0.98\TblrNote{***} & 1.10\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.10\TblrNote{***} & 0.77\TblrNote{***} & 1.17\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.23\TblrNote{***} & 1.02\TblrNote{***} & 1.07\TblrNote{***}  \\
Fin. Knowledge
        & 2.08\TblrNote{***} & 0.80\TblrNote{***} & 2.11\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.58\TblrNote{***} & 0.57\TblrNote{***} & 2.00\TblrNote{***}
        & 2.18\TblrNote{***} & 0.94\TblrNote{***} & 2.38\TblrNote{***}  \\
Income  & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{*}   & 1.00\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***}  \\
Networth
        & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{**}  &  1.00\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***}  \\
        \cmidrule[lr]{2-4}
                \cmidrule[lr]{5-7}
                        \cmidrule[l]{8-10}
Observations
    & \SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{26212}}}  &   &
            & \SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{21183}}} &  &
                    & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {{{5028}}}  &  &                \\
AIC & \SetCell[c=3]{c}    {{{42,258.51}}}   &  &
            & \SetCell[c=3]{c}    {{{7,681.80}}}  &  &
                    & \SetCell[c=3]{c}    {{{34,677.61}}} &   &         \\
Log Likelihood
    &  \SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{BLA}}} &   &
            & \SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{BLA}}}  &   &
                & \SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{BLA}}}  &   &                     \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\pagebreak
        & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {{{BchMk}}} &  &
                &\SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{CCP.0}}}  &  &
                       &\SetCell[c=3]{c}  {{{CCP.1}}}  &  & \\
Variables
        & {{{Fml}}}     & {{{Infm}}}    & {{{Both}}}
        & {{{Fml}}}     & {{{Infm}}}    & {{{Both}}}
        & {{{Fml}}}     & {{{Infm}}}    & {{{Both}}}                    \\
        \cmidrule[lr]{2-4}
                \cmidrule[lr=-0.5]{5-7}
                        \cmidrule[l=-0.5]{8-10}
Gender  & 0.84\TblrNote{***} & 1.11\TblrNote{***} & 0.97\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.87\TblrNote{***} & 1.17\TblrNote{***} & 0.98\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.84\TblrNote{***} & 1.15\TblrNote{***} & 0.97\TblrNote{***}  \\
Marital Status
        & 1.94\TblrNote{***} & 1.15\TblrNote{***} & 1.93\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.45\TblrNote{***} & 1.16\TblrNote{***} & 2.53\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.94\TblrNote{***} & 1.13\TblrNote{***} & 1.95\TblrNote{***}  \\
Age     & 0.95\TblrNote{***} & 0.98\TblrNote{***} & 0.95\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.94\TblrNote{***} & 0.97\TblrNote{***} & 0.94\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.95\TblrNote{***} & 0.98\TblrNote{***} & 0.95\TblrNote{***}  \\
Employed
        & 1.61\TblrNote{***} & 1.07\TblrNote{***} & 1.57\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.72\TblrNote{***} & 1.20\TblrNote{***} & 2.30\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.57\TblrNote{***} & 1.01\TblrNote{***} & 1.38\TblrNote{***}  \\
Education
        & 2.08\TblrNote{***} & 0.62\TblrNote{***} & 1.16\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.97\TblrNote{***} & 0.73\TblrNote{***} & 1.28\TblrNote{***}
        & 2.04\TblrNote{***} & 0.65\TblrNote{***} & 1.07\TblrNote{***}  \\
Party   & 1.44\TblrNote{***} & 0.78\TblrNote{***} & 1.13\TblrNote{***}
            & {{{---}}} & {{{---}}} &{{{---}}}
                            & {{{---}}} & {{{--}}} & {{{---}}}          \\
HR      & 1.52\TblrNote{***} & 0.65\TblrNote{***} & 0.72\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.77\TblrNote{***} & 0.51\TblrNote{***} & 0.58\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.50\TblrNote{***} & 0.66\TblrNote{***} & 0.80\TblrNote{***}  \\
Region-East
        & 0.77\TblrNote{***} & 0.66\TblrNote{***} & 0.56\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.95\TblrNote{***} & 0.54\TblrNote{***} & 0.58\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.78\TblrNote{***} & 0.66\TblrNote{***} & 0.51\TblrNote{***}  \\
Region-Center
        & 0.64\TblrNote{***} & 1.03\TblrNote{***} & 0.76\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.90\TblrNote{***} & 0.97\TblrNote{***} & 0.84\TblrNote{***}
        & 0.60\TblrNote{***} & 1.01\TblrNote{***} & 0.72\TblrNote{***}  \\
Fin. Inter
        & 1.23\TblrNote{***} & 0.98\TblrNote{***} & 1.10\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.10\TblrNote{***} & 0.77\TblrNote{***} & 1.17\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.23\TblrNote{***} & 1.02\TblrNote{***} & 1.07\TblrNote{***}  \\
Fin. Knowledge
        & 2.08\TblrNote{***} & 0.80\TblrNote{***} & 2.11\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.58\TblrNote{***} & 0.57\TblrNote{***} & 2.00\TblrNote{***}
        & 2.18\TblrNote{***} & 0.94\TblrNote{***} & 2.38\TblrNote{***}  \\
Income  & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{*}   & 1.00\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***}  \\
Networth
        & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{**}  &  1.00\TblrNote{***}
        & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***} & 1.00\TblrNote{***}  \\
%
        \cmidrule[lr]{2-4}
                \cmidrule[lr]{5-7}
                        \cmidrule[l]{8-10}
Observations
    & \SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{26212}}}  &   &
            & \SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{21183}}} &  &
                    & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  {{{5028}}}  &  &                \\
AIC & \SetCell[c=3]{c}    {{{42,258.51}}}   &  &
            & \SetCell[c=3]{c}    {{{7,681.80}}}  &  &
                    & \SetCell[c=3]{c}    {{{34,677.61}}} &   &         \\
Log Likelihood
    &  \SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{BLA}}} &   &
            & \SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{BLA}}}  &   &
                & \SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{BLA}}}  &   &                     \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, you meant the word exercise seriously :) thanks for the `\NewChildSelector` example.

Answer (score 1):

Use `xltabular`. It is a combination of `tabularx` and `longtable`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{xltabular}{1\textwidth}{l*{9}{R}} 
     \caption{MLM.1: Multinominal logistic models.\label{tab:MLM-1}} \\ \toprule    
        Variables  &  Fml  &  Infm  &  Both  &  Fml  &  Infm  &  Both  &  Fml  &  Infm  &  Both \\ 
        \midrule 
        %\addlinespace
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{BchMk} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{CCP.0} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{CCP.1} \\ 
        \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10}   
        %\addlinespace
        Gender  & 0.84$^{***}$ & 1.11$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ & 0.87$^{***}$ &   1.17$^{***}$ &  
        0.98$^{***}$ & 0.84$^{***}$ &  1.15$^{***}$ &   0.97$^{***}$ \\
        Marital Status& 1.94$^{***}$ &   1.15$^{***}$ &  1.93$^{***}$ &  1.45$^{***}$ &  
        1.16$^{***}$ &  2.53$^{***}$  &1.94$^{***}$ &   1.13$^{***}$ &  1.95$^{***}$\\
        Age &    0.95$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$ &  0.94$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ &  
        0.94$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$\\
        Employed    & 1.61$^{***}$ &     1.07$^{***}$ &  1.57$^{***}$ &  1.72$^{***}$ &  
        1.20$^{***}$ &  2.30$^{***}$ &  1.57$^{***}$ &  1.01$^{***}$ &  1.38$^{***}$  \\
        Education &  2.08$^{***}$ &  0.62$^{***}$ &  1.16$^{***}$ &  1.97$^{***}$ &  0.73$^{***}$ 
        &  1.28$^{***}$  & 2.04$^{***}$ &  0.65$^{***}$ &  1.07$^{***}$\\
        Party&   1.44$^{***}$ &  0.78$^{***}$ &  1.13$^{***}$ &  -----  & -----   & -----  &    
        -----   & -----  & -----    \\
        HR  & 1.52$^{***}$ &     0.65$^{***}$ &  0.72$^{***}$ & 1.77$^{***}$ &   0.51$^{***}$ &  
        0.58$^{***}$  &     1.50$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.80$^{***}$  \\
        Region-East &    0.77$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.56$^{***}$ & 0.95$^{***}$ &   
        0.54$^{***}$ &  0.58$^{***}$   &    0.78$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.51$^{***}$\\
        Region-Center &  0.64$^{***}$ &  1.03$^{***}$ &  0.76$^{***}$ &  0.90$^{***}$ &  
        0.97$^{***}$ &  0.84$^{***}$  &     0.60$^{***}$ &  1.01$^{***}$ &  0.72$^{***}$\\
        Fin.Inter &  1.23$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  1.10$^{***}$ & 1.10$^{***}$ &   0.77$^{***}$ 
        &  1.17$^{***}$ & 1.23$^{***}$ &   1.02$^{***}$ &  1.07$^{***}$   \\
        Fin.Knowledge   & 2.08$^{***}$ &     0.80$^{***}$ &  2.11$^{***}$ &  1.58$^{***}$ &  
        0.57$^{***}$ &  2.00$^{***}$ &  2.18$^{***}$ &  0.94$^{***}$ &  2.38$^{***}$   \\
        Income  & 1.00$^{***}$ &     1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{*}$ 
        &    1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$   \\
        Networth &   1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{**}$ 
        &   1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$\\
        \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10} 
        Observations   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{26212} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{21183}  & 
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{5028}\\ 
        AIC  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{42,266.04} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{7,688.11}  & 
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{34,686.78}\\ 
        \toprule 
        %\addlinespace
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{BchMk} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{CCP.0} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{CCP.1} \\ 
        \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10} 
        %\addlinespace 
        Gender  &    0.83$^{***}$ &  1.11$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ &  0.86$^{***}$ &  1.17$^{***}$ 
        &  0.97$^{***}$  & 0.84$^{***}$ & 1.15$^{***}$ & 0.98$^{***}$   \\
        Marital Status  &    1.98$^{***}$ &  1.14$^{***}$ &  1.97$^{***}$ & 1.48$^{***}$ &   
        1.15$^{***}$ &  2.57$^{***}$  & 1.98$^{***}$ &  1.13$^{***}$ &  1.97$^{***}$    \\
        Age  &   0.95$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$ &  0.94$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ &  
        0.94$^{***}$  &     0.95$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$   \\
        Employed  &  1.60$^{***}$ &  1.06$^{***}$ &  1.56$^{***}$ &  1.69$^{***}$ &  1.20$^{***}$ 
        &  2.27$^{***}$ &  1.57$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.36$^{***}$  \\
        Education  & 2.12$^{***}$ &  0.62$^{***}$ &  1.19$^{***}$ &  2.02$^{***}$ &  0.73$^{***}$ 
        &  1.31$^{***}$  &     2.11$^{***}$ &  0.64$^{***}$ &  1.10$^{***}$    \\
        Party  &     1.45$^{***}$ &  0.78$^{***}$ &  1.14$^{***}$ &     -----  &    -----   & ----- 
        & -----     & -----     & ----- \\
        HR  &    1.56$^{***}$ &  0.64$^{***}$ &  0.74$^{***}$ &  1.83$^{***}$ &  0.50$^{***}$ &  
        0.60$^{***}$  &     1.54$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.81$^{***}$ \\
        Region-East  &   0.79$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.58$^{***}$ & 1.00$^{***}$ &   
        0.54$^{***}$ &  0.61$^{***}$ &  0.79$^{***}$ &  0.65$^{***}$ &  0.55$^{***}$  \\
        Region-Center  &     0.64$^{***}$ &  1.03$^{***}$ &  0.76$^{***}$ &  0.90$^{***}$ &  
        0.97$^{***}$ &  0.85$^{***}$  &     0.59$^{***}$ &  1.01$^{***}$ &  0.74$^{***}$   \\
        Fin.Inter  &     1.24$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  1.12$^{***}$ &  1.11$^{***}$ &  
        0.77$^{***}$ &  1.18$^{***}$  &     1.25$^{***}$ &  1.02$^{***}$ &  1.09$^{***}$     \\
        Fin.Knowledge  &     2.14$^{***}$ &  0.79$^{***}$ &  2.19$^{***}$ & 1.60$^{***}$ &   
        0.57$^{***}$ &  2.05$^{***}$   &    2.21$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  2.39$^{***}$  \\
        Income  &    1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{**}$ 
        &   1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$  \\
        NW-HE &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ & 1.00$^{***}$ &   1.00$^{*}$ &    
        1.00$^{**}$  &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$\\
        \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10}       
        Observations  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{26212} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{21183} & 
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{5028}\\
        AIC  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{42,422.85} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{7,732.85}  & 
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{34,802.33}\\ 
        \toprule 
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{BchMk} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{CCP.0} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{CCP.1} \\ 
        \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10} 
        %\addlinespace 
        Gender  &    0.84$^{***}$ &  1.11$^{***}$ &  0.97$^{***}$ &  0.87$^{***}$ &  1.17$^{***}$ 
        &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.85$^{***}$ &  1.15$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$     \\
        Marital Status  &    1.93$^{***}$ &  1.15$^{***}$ &  1.92$^{***}$ &  1.44$^{***}$ &  
        1.15$^{***}$ &  2.50$^{***}$ &  1.93$^{***}$ &  1.13$^{***}$ &  1.93$^{***}$  \\
        Age  &   0.95$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$ & 0.94$^{***}$ &   0.97$^{***}$ &  
        0.94$^{***}$  &     0.95$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  0.95$^{***}$ \\
        Employed  &  1.61$^{***}$ &  1.07$^{***}$ &  1.57$^{***}$ & 1.72$^{***}$ &   1.19$^{***}$ 
        &  2.31$^{***}$ &  1.58$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.37$^{***}$  \\
        Education  &     2.07$^{***}$ &  0.62$^{***}$ &  1.16$^{***}$ & 1.96$^{***}$ &   
        0.73$^{***}$ &  1.28$^{***}$  &     2.07$^{***}$ &  0.65$^{***}$ &  1.07$^{***}$  \\
        Party  &     1.43$^{***}$ &  0.78$^{***}$ &  1.13$^{***}$ &     -----  & -----    &   ----- 
        & -----       & -----   &   -----  \\
        HR  &    1.51$^{***}$ &  0.64$^{***}$ &  0.72$^{***}$ &  1.76$^{***}$ &  0.51$^{***}$ &  
        0.58$^{***}$  &     1.49$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.78$^{***}$ \\
        Region-East  &   0.77$^{***}$ &  0.66$^{***}$ &  0.56$^{***}$ & 0.94$^{***}$ &   
        0.54$^{***}$ &  0.57$^{***}$  &     0.77$^{***}$ &  0.65$^{***}$ &  0.53$^{***}$    \\
        Region-Center  &     0.64$^{***}$ &  1.03$^{***}$ &  0.76$^{***}$ &  0.90$^{***}$ &  
        0.97$^{***}$ &  0.84$^{***}$ &  0.60$^{***}$ &  1.01$^{***}$ &  0.75$^{***}$   \\
        Fin.Inter  &     1.22$^{***}$ &  0.98$^{***}$ &  1.10$^{***}$ & 1.10$^{***}$ &   
        0.77$^{***}$ &  1.17$^{***}$   &    1.23$^{***}$ &  1.02$^{***}$ &  1.08$^{***}$ \\
        Fin.Knowldge  &  2.07$^{***}$ &  0.79$^{***}$ &  2.10$^{***}$ & 1.57$^{***}$ &   
        0.57$^{***}$ &  1.99$^{***}$ &  2.14$^{***}$ &  0.99$^{***}$ &  2.30$^{***}$  \\
        Income  &    1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ & 1.00$^{***}$ &   1.00$^{*}$ 
        &    1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$\\
        Liquid Assets  &     1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ & 1.00$^{***}$ &   
        1.00$^{**}$ &   1.00$^{***}$  &     1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$ &  1.00$^{***}$  \\
        \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10}   
        Observations  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{26212} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{21183} & 
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{5028}\\
        AIC   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{42,258.51} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{7,681.80}  & 
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{34,677.61}\\ 
        %   Log Likelihood  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{BLA} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{BLA}  & 
        %\multicolumn{3}{c}{BLA}\\ 
        \bottomrule
        \addlinespace
        \multicolumn{10}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\footnotesize Note: Multinominal Logistic Model with 
        Networth as Predictor. Relative Risk Ratios (RRR) are reported with significance: 
        $^*p<0.1;~^{**}p<0.05;~^{***}p<0.01$. 
            The variables and abbreviations can be found 
            %in Appendix \ref{tab:def.of.vars} and Appendix \ref{tab:abbreviations}, respectively. 
        }
\end{xltabular}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is very nice.  But I was wondering If I can cut the table from the second AIC. like 2 tables on the first page followed by the last table on the second page.

Comment: with \pagebreak, got it thanks.

Comment: everything what is possible for `longtable` is possible for `xltabular`, too: Repeating headers, footers, and so on.